# Python 3.3.2 - Why does my def function not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
global_var = 1

def my_vars():
    print( 'Global Variable:' , local_var )

    local_var = 2
    print( 'Local variable:' , local_var )

    global inner_var
    inner_var = 3

my_vars()

print( 'Coerced Global:' , inner_var )
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, please take a look at [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `local_var` before having assigned to it. What were you expecting?

```
print( 'Global Variable:' , local_var )  # did you mean global_var?
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, rookie mistake that I kept over looking... My head is a bit fried this morning, trying to learn as much as I can is taking its toll on me!